# How to send directories with spaces to another command?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have searched extensively for the answer to this question and can not find a solution:

So far, I have used the `find` command to locate all files with a keyword in the title and pass this list to a file.

`find ./ -name "*keyword*" > filepath.txt`  Easy enough.

The problem is as follows.  Say the command finds three files:

```
/Documents/somefolder/keyword file 1.txt
/Documents/some other folder/keyword2.txt 
/Documents/a third folder/keyword file 3.txt
```

The results return directories and files with spaces in the names.  I am trying to write a simple bash script that will take each line of filepath.txt and pair it with the `cp` or `mv` command to automatically move or copy those files which were located with the `find` command.  The problem is that bash does not interpret the file paths literally and will return 'No such file or directory'.  I tried copying a script that reads words in a file as follows, but it is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
for path in $(tr -d \; < filepath.txt); do
     mv $path ~/home/Documents/Newfolder
done
```

There are hundreds of files in my results and hunting them all down to rename them is simply not feasible.

Comment: Typical newbie error: You missed to double quote `$path` during usage. And another question: Why are you trying to delete a semicolon from input file? And there are other errors too. Please read  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: I tried "$path" and '$path' both.  For "$path", it returns the same errors (using the echo command instead of mv command)  For '$path' it echoes the literal string '$path' and for "$path" it returns the same errors of no such file or directory.

What should the script look like?

Answer (score 2):

You have fallen into [bash pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

You can reliably do what you want with a `while` loop, as follows:

```
while IFS= read -r path; do
  cp -n -- "$path" ~/home/Documents/Newfolder/
done < filepath.txt
```

Note the trailing slash on the target directory - this prevents mishaps if the directory doesn't exist - and the `-n` to prevent overwriting files of the same name.

You could also consider using `xargs` with newline as the delimiter:

```
xargs -d '\n' cp -nt ~/home/Documents/Newfolder/ < filepath.txt
```

Here I'm using the GNU `-t` form of the `mv` command to specify a single target directory for multiple files.

Alternatively, you could have saved all the bother by omitting the intermediate file, and moved or copied the files from `find` using the `-exec` or `-execdir` action:

```
find ./ -name "*keyword*" -exec cp -nt ~/home/Documents/Newfolder/ {} +
```

---

*I have retained your path `~/home/Documents/Newfolder/` even though I doubt it's what you really want (it would expand to `/home/username/home/Documents/Newfolder`).*